# How to populate the Combobox in VBdotNet

Tags: vb.net

How to pupolate the Combobox in VB.Net, the items are from DataSet... Here's my code

```
Dim LibDSPopulate As New DataSet
        Dim LibDAPopulate As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM tblBooks", LibConn)
        LibDAPopulate.Fill(LibDSPopulate, "tblBooks")

        cmbCategoryF.Items.Add(LibDSPopulate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Data binding [facility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx#Y300).

```
'Add an empty entry 
Dim dr As DataRow = LibDSPopulate.Tables("tblBooks").NewRow
dr("Category") = "***Select***"
LibDSPopulate.Tables("tblBooks").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)

cmbCategoryF.DataSource=LibDSPopulate.Tables("tblBooks")
cmbCategoryF.DisplayMember="Category" 'Name of field
cmbCategoryF.ValueMember="Category"   'Name of field
```

If you don't want to use databindng then add each item using Items.Add() method.

```
 For Each row As DataRow In LibDSPopulate.Tables("tblBooks").Rows
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(row("Category"))
 Next
```

Comment: using the DataBinding... Where the empty item (placed at 0-row in cmbCategoryF) came from? I'm trying to remove it... and thanks for that tutorial you have provided...

Comment: @aerohn - You have to add an empty entry in DataTable if you are using dataBinding. See my edited post.

Comment: yes, gotcha!
I really enjoy learning new things in programming :)